# Unknown error (our of memory)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following cypher query times out in Community 2.0.1.  Unfortunately, I was unable to generate a `profile` output with it.

I am looking to disambiguate a user if they have been duplicated, and trying to find a baseline if this has occured with a specific user.  However, it looks as though Cypher is not 'starting' with the two nodes that have the same `apiid`, but rather is querying all the relationships in the database first.

```
match (n:LIuser)-[r:CONNECTED]-(), (nnn:LIuser)-[rr:CONNECTED]-()
where n.apiid = 'K1J3V8EI9M' 
    and nnn.apiid = '29302231'
return count(distinct r), count(distinct rr)
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Edit: I realize that I miss typed this question - which completely changes the meaning.  n.apiid and nnn.apiid are DIFFERENT.  I had originally typed them as being the same.

Comment: you can generate a profile by going to http://localhost:7474/webadmin and to the Console tab there and adding profile in front of your query

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a cross product, that's the issue.

Imagine you have 1000 CONNECTED queries for each of these users, then you create 1000 x 1000 rows that have to be processed. (Not that 1M rows would be an issue normally). Perhaps you should also share your setup and `graph.db/messages.log`

Actually if I understood you correctly what you want is an grouping, which would return 2 or more rows for duplicate users with their counts ?

```
MATCH (n:LIuser)-[r:CONNECTED]-()
WHERE n.apiid = 'K1J3V8EI9M' 
RETURN n, count(distinct r)
```

You could even do this to see what is on the other side then:

```
MATCH (n:LIuser)-[r:CONNECTED]-(m)
WHERE n.apiid = 'K1J3V8EI9M' 
RETURN n, count(distinct r),collect(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying indexing on the `apiid` property?

`CREATE INDEX ON :LIuser(apiid)`

Comment: Great suggestion @satoru - there is actually already an index on that label/property